# Types of Extensions in TMediaPlayer - delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

Good day ... 
I wonder what kind of extension that are accepted TMediaPlayer with Delphi ... Both audio and video ...

```
(MP1, MP2, MP3, Wma, WAV etc... vídeo AVI, MP4 ETC...
```

Which extensions without codecs ... he plays?? and he plays every codec??

Because I like to know when an extension does not exist ...

```
 if (F.Name <> '.') And (F.Name <> '..') then
      if Sub = True then
      begin
        TempNome := Diretorio+'\' + F.Name;
        ListarArquivos(TempNome, True);
      end;
  end
  else
  begin
      if verificaExtesao(F.Name) then
      Begin
        ContaArquivos := ContaArquivos +1;
        memLista.Lines.Add(Diretorio+'\'+F.Name);
        Label2.Caption := IntToStr(ContaArquivos);
      End;
```

Comment: Any kind. Particular *file types* depends on the installed codecs.

Comment: It's a wrapper for MCI. See "[MCI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd742874(v=vs.85).aspx)" on MSDN.